# toEndOf not working in custom dialog layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making a custom dialog, with two buttons in the lower part. This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/dialog_container">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/questiontitle"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:text="@string/newquestion"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/writequestion"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/questiontitle"
    android:text="@string/writequestion"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/question"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/writequestion"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:hint="@string/questionhint" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/question"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/centerview"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cancelbutton"
    android:text="@string/cancel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/question"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/centerview"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/okbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/question"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/centerview"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/ok"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the layout design tab, in Android Studio, it is showing perfectly, but running in the phone (Samsung J7) the okbutton is filling the parent width... Why is that? I want the buttons aligned to the bottom of the RelativeLayout, one to the left of the other.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hade some wrong alignments so I fixed them for you, generally, you really did most of the work in a really nice way.
 For future layouts, I want to recommend to use [constraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout), it's really nice, easy to use and responsive to the different screen sizes. 
 
**Here is the new layout(i also checked it on galaxy j7)** :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/questiontitle"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="newquestion"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/writequestion"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/questiontitle"
        android:text="writequestion"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/writequestion"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:hint="questionhint" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/question"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/centerview"/>

    <Button

        android:id="@+id/cancelbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/question"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/centerview"
        android:text="cancel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/okbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/question"
        android:text="ok"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/centerview"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks...I copypasted your XML, and it is not showing properly. I have a "cancel" button filling width of the screen...

Comment: That's weird, its working perfectly for me, are you using the exact XML that I posted? did you add backgrounds or something?

Comment: I added background to the RelativeLayout, and drawable to the button. I am adding it to the question.

Comment: And without those addings - do you have this problem?

Comment: 1 more thing - try to add   android:layout_centerVertical="true" into your editText with the id of "centerview"

Comment: Whitout adding it, I have cancel button stick to the left of the screen. But I just realized the buttonshape.xml has a size attribute (I didn't make it). I am changing it to see if it fixes my problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188832/discussion-between-tamir-abutbul-and-fustigador).